# Plotly Express Scatter_Mapbox Returns Blank

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-express

I'm using plotly express, specifically scatter_mapbox to plot some locations on a map. This morning it was working fine via Jupyter Notebook. I wanted to save it so I called fig.write_image(), I got an error saying I need to install Kaleido, which I did. Ever since that point when the figure will not show, rather a big blank space appears in my notebook.

I've tried:

```
fig.show("notebook")
```

I've also restarted the kernel and other suggestions found [here.](https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/) Nothing works.

I've also uninstalled and reinstalled plotly.

I'm using notebook version 6.4.6 and plotly 5.5.0

I've done a lot of googling and this appears to be an issue for some, but none of the fixes I've seen work. For reference here is the code creating the plot.

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(ad, lat="lat", lon="long", hover_name="Name", hover_data=["City", "State"], size_max=5, zoom=4,
                   color_discrete_sequence=["#006039"])
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't have my mapbox token referenced in the code. Sorry, all.

Answer (score 0):

Update your chrome. You need to be able to use open GL. I had the same issue and  after updating chrome it worked.